# How to solve rake tasks deprecation on the rails plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Because of the concept introduced in [here](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb),

> Rails::Plugin is nothing more than a
>   Rails::Engine, but since it's loaded
>   too late in the boot process, it does
>   not have the same configuration powers
>   as a bare Rails::Engine.
>
> Opposite to Rails::Railtie and
>   Rails::Engine, you are not supposed to
>   inherit from Rails::Plugin.
>   Rails::Plugin is automatically
>   configured to be an engine by simply
>   placing inside vendor/plugins. Since
>   this is done automatically, you
>   actually cannot declare a
>   Rails::Engine inside your Plugin,
>   otherwise it would cause the same
>   files to be loaded twice. This means
>   that if you want to ship an Engine as
>   gem it cannot be used as plugin and
>   vice-versa.
>
> Besides this conceptual difference,
>   the only difference between
>   Rails::Engine and Rails::Plugin is
>   that plugins automatically load the
>   file "init.rb" at the plugin root
>   during the boot process.

rake tasks in the rails plugins are deprecated and it is advised to use lib/tasks instead. How to solve this? Can I just simply move the plugin's tasks to the lib/tasks?

Answer (score 9):

i've just had the same problem here, just moved all the vendor/plugin/*/tasks/*.rake files to lib/tasks (had to create this directory because it didn't existed)

then rake rails:update ran fine

Comment: This does appear to work.  However I am still curious as to what the replacement for this behaviour is supposed to be.  i.e., how do plugins define new tasks now?

Comment: they're all in RAILS_ROOT/tasks/, that's why just moving them fix this issue, it is the same thing but on different place

Comment: To move all those files at once from the command-line, from your project's root directory, run `mkdir lib/tasks` and then `mv vendor/plugins/*/tasks/*.rake lib/tasks`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're the developer of a plugin, you would simply move

```
my_cool_plugin/tasks
```

to

```
my_cool_plugin/lib/tasks
```