# DEPRECATION WARNING in Rails `bundle exec rake`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to solve rake tasks deprecation on the rails plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858165/how-to-solve-rake-tasks-deprecation-on-the-rails-plugin)

I have cloned a rails app from a git repository. Have ran `bundle install` 
to install required gems.

But after running `bundle exec rake db:create` the error below shows up. I checked my database and no database was created after running the command. What might be wrong? Thanks.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/annotate_models/tasks, vendor/plugins/ar_fixtures/tasks, vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, vendor/plugins/limerick_rake/tasks, and vendor/plugins/ultrasphinx/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/neilmarion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
```